# How to set a byte in NSMutableData

Tags: objective-c, arrays, byte, nsmutabledata

How would I set a byte in an NSMutableData object?
I tried the following:

```
-(void)setFirstValue:(Byte)v{
    [mValues mutableBytes][0] = v;
}
```

But that makes the compiler cry out loud...

Answer (score 5):

> But that makes the compiler cry out loud...

That is because `mutableBytes*` returns `void*`. Cast it to `char*` to fix the problem:

```
((char*)[mValues mutableBytes])[0] = v;
```

You could also use `replaceBytesInRange:withBytes:`

```
char buf[1];
buf[0] = v;
[mValues replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withBytes:buf];
```

Answer (score 1):

I cast it to an array

```
    NSMutableData * rawData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data];
    NSMutableArray * networkBuffer = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    const uint8_t *bytes = [self.rawData bytes];

    //cycle through data and place it in the network buffer
    for (int i =0; i < [data length]; i++) 
    {
        [networkBuffer addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X", bytes[i]]];
    }
```

then of course you can just adjust objects in your networkBuffer (which is an nsmutablearray)